# MVC 3 Controller not recognizing JSON passed back by jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an MVC 3 app that is using jQuery AJAX to fire off a controller action to return a partial view.

The client side code:

```
function getCustomerList(searchCriteria) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/GetCustomerList',
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{searchString:"' + searchCriteria + '"}',
        success: function (result) {
            $("#customerTabBody").html(result);
        }
    });
};
```

The Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCustomerList(string searchString)
{
    var custService = new CustomerViewModels();
    var custListVM = custService.GetSearchList(searchString);

    return PartialView("GetCustomerList", custListVM);
}
```

When I fire the client side jQuery I can see via Firebug that the searchString is being sent and appears properly formatted.  Here's what Firebug shows as the post message:

{searchString:'ar'}

and Firebug is able to properly parse the JSON.  If I put a breakpoint in the controller code and test the value of the searchString parameter is is NULL.  However if I just hardcode the JSON:

```
function getCustomerList(searchCriteria) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/GetCustomerList',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {searchString:'ar'},
        success: function (result) {
            $("#customerTabBody").html(result);
        }
    });
};
```

It works perfectly and the controller parameter is correctly populated.

What am I doing wrong such that when I parametrize my JSON string it fails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function getCustomerList(searchCriteria) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/GetCustomerList',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { searchString: searchCriteria },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#customerTabBody').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

This will ensure that the data sent to the controller is properly URL encoded. Also you haven't shown how/where you are calling this `getCustomerList` function but if it is on the click of some anchor or button make sure that you are cancelling the default action as well.

Comment: Folks - We have a winner!  Thanks Darin

Comment: Weird that StackOverflow makes you wait about 12 minutes before you can mark an answer as correct.